# HTMLPurifier syntax issue

Tags: htmlpurifier

I am using HTMLPurifier with this config:

```
case 'comment':
$config = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
config->set('Core.Encoding', 'utf-8');

$config->set('HTML.Allowed', 'iframe[src|width|height|frameborder|allowfullscreen],p[style],p,br,hr,center,em,u,ul,li,font,ol,div[class|style],span[style],blockquote,strike,b,strong, img[src|alt|class|height|width],a[href|rel],object[width|height|data], param[name|value],embed[src|type|allowfullscreen|width|height]');

$config->set('HTML.SafeIframe', true);
$config->set('URI.SafeIframeRegexp', '%^//(www.youtube.com/embed/|player.vimeo.com/video/)%');    

$config->set('Cache.DefinitionImpl', null); // TODO: remove this later!

break;
```

The allowfullscreen attribute is stripped when embedding youtube videos.
why?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the attribute is not supported by the SafeIframe at the moment. You can program in support yourself using http://htmlpurifier.org/docs/enduser-customize.html